# SMTP.SendAsync not working correctly

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, smtp, task

I am trying to get familiar with the smtp.SendAsync and for some reason I am not able to get the mailmessage to send Async.

Here is what I've tried.

```
//smtp.SendAsync(mm, null)); Error, Async operation was attempted before another one completed

//Task.Run(() => smtp.SendAsync(mm, null)); No error and no email

//smtp.SendMailAsync(mm));Error, Async operation was attempted before another one completed

// Task.Run(() => smtp.SendMailAsync(mm)); No error and no email.

//smtp.Send(mm); The only one that works, but has that delay and that is what I am attempting to get away from.
```

My code:

```
public static void Email(IElevation elevation, string fromEmail, string toEmail)
{

    using (Bitmap printCanvas = ShopDrawing.Merger.MergeElevationAndDoor(elevation, RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone))
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            printCanvas.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            ms.Position = 0;

            using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(new MailAddress(fromEmail), new MailAddress(toEmail)))
            {
                mm.Subject = "[Project: " + elevation.ProjectName + "] " + " Shop drawings for " + elevation.Name;
                mm.Body = "Your shop drawings are attached to this email in reference to Project: " + elevation.ProjectName + " -> Elevation: " + elevation.Name;
                Attachment at = new Attachment(ms, elevation.Name + ".png", "image/png");
                mm.Attachments.Add(at);
                using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    //smtp.SendAsync(mm, null));
                    //Task.Run(() => smtp.SendAsync(mm, null));
                    //smtp.SendMailAsync(mm));
                    // Task.Run(() => smtp.SendMailAsync(mm));

                    //The only one that works
                    smtp.Send(mm);

                };
            };
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: You have to `await` the `SendMailAsync` call or the `SmtpClient` will be disposed while the email is being sent.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I've got the code above in a class library. I cannot find the reference in the "Add Reference" dialog. Any idea of how to import or gain access to the await?

Comment: Although not a direct answer you could wrap the `smtp.Send` part with `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` we've done that before to make it psuedo asynchronous.

Comment: Both of the comments are very helpful to me. I didn't know which one to up-vote so I tossed a coin. I was finally able to get it with the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem. I am calling this method from a WebAPIController and it was getting complicated. I am trying to get to where I understand the await with the WebApi but it is taking a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Wrapped the entire body of the function in a ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem from @Lloyd help.

```
  public static void EmailShopDrawingAndDoorSchedule(IElevation elevation, string fromEmail, string toEmail)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(t =>
                       {
                           using (Bitmap printCanvas = ShopDrawing.Merger.MergeElevationAndDoor(elevation, RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone))
                           {
                               using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                               {
                                   printCanvas.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                                   ms.Position = 0;

                                   using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(new MailAddress(fromEmail), new MailAddress(toEmail)))
                                   {
                                       mm.Subject = "[Project: " + elevation.ProjectName + "] " + " Shop drawings for " + elevation.Name;
                                       mm.Body = "Your shop drawings are attached to this email in reference to Project: " + elevation.ProjectName + " -> Elevation: " + elevation.Name;

                                       using (Attachment at = new Attachment(ms, elevation.Name + ".png", "image/png"))
                                       {
                                           mm.Attachments.Add(at);

                                           using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
                                           {
                                               smtp.Send(mm);
                                           };

                                       }
                                   };
                               };
                           };
                       });
    }
```